# Android Studio Not showing button in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio doesn't show any buttons or textview in GridLayout, but when I put it in constraint layout it shows up properly and it even works fine when I run the app in the emulator:

[Here's the Screen Shot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNr6e.jpg)

This is how the xml file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="514dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="291dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="291dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I am getting this error:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqaa4.jpg)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `works fine when I run the app in the emulator` - so what is the issue?

Comment: Yes it works fine in the emulator, but it's not rendering the button properly in the design tab in android studio, why is that? I want this to work cause my pc is really slow and so I can't run the app repeated on the emulator , it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the **<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>** or **<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>** tag instead with `<GridLayout>`

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</GridLayout>
```